# Array query parameter for Ruby Grape API

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

Right now my API accepts a request such as `?a[]=x&a[]=y` using:

```
params do
  requires :a, type: Array[String]
end
```

My client can only send the query parameter as `?a[0]=x&a[1]=y` which Grape does *not* understand, resulting in **400 (Bad Request)**.

Is it not possible to both accept `a[]` and `a[0]` with Grape? The other option is to send a request to another server first, converting from `a[0]` to `a[]`, send that request to Grape, get the response from Grape and send that to the client, which seems really unnecessary.

Comment: What prevents your client to generate such URLs?

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to change from indices to brackets using the library, so maybe it was easier to change Grape to be more flexible. I could construct the parameters myself of course but I thought libraries should handle that. Qs (https://github.com/hapijs/qs#stringifying) can handle that for example, specifying brackets or indices easily (I am not using Qs however).

Answer (score 3):

It is more to do with Rack than Grape. It's how Rack parses query strings, take a look at

rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/utils.rb

```
def parse_nested_query(qs, d = nil)
  params = KeySpaceConstrainedParams.new

  (qs || '').split(d ? /[#{d}] */n : DEFAULT_SEP).each do |p|
    k, v = p.split('=', 2).map { |s| unescape(s) }

    normalize_params(params, k, v)
  end

  return params.to_params_hash
rescue ArgumentError => e
  raise InvalidParameterError, e.message
end
```

`?a[0]=x&a[1]=y` will produce a hash `=> {"a"=>{"0"=>"x", "1"=>"y"}}`, which based on the `params` is invalid.

While a non-indiced version `?a[]=x&a[]=y` produces an array `{"a"=>["1", "2"]}`

For some great information on that @see http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query